# iphone Displaying alert with multiple buttons at application's first launch

Tags: iphone

i want to display an alert at first launch of application, and that alert will contain multiple buttons, like first button title can be student, second can be businessman, third can be professional, 4th can be engineer, means different categorie, and when user presses any button i want to save its title as a string in data base, like if user pressed student button i want to save student in the db, the save into db process is not a problem, but i only want to know that how can i display this kind of alert? and at only the first launch of application and also get value on user click, plz. guide me in this, Regards  Saad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIAlertView can do that for you, it allows to send an array of strings for the button titles.
Add the code in the app delegate class in applicationDidFinishLaunching, or in the viewDidLoad of the first view controller.
Also use `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` to save the settings. it works like a dictionary. if the value is there then you saved it before so its not the first run. if the value of that key is nil, then this is the 1st run.

Update:

```
UIAlertView *alrt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!" message:@"Unable to complete Request.\nPlease try again later" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Demo Button1",@"Demo Button 2",nil];
[alrt show];
[alrt release];
```

your delegate needs to implement `UIAlertViewDelegate` to know which button the user pressed. delegate method is `-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`

Comment: ok i got your point about first launch, but can you explain (any example or tutorial link) a little about alert with multiple buttons, plz., coz i am still little confused about it,. thanx.

Comment: Updated the answer. I took the code from a project i have and added "Demo Button" 1 and 2 to show you how it works

Comment: thanx Ehab Amer i successfully implemented that but the last button displaying with double space with respect to other buttons, means i have added titles of 5 buttons, all four buttons are at same distance from each other vertically, but the last button has double the distancs, how to resolve it.?

Comment: try to set the cancelButtonTitle to nil (thats the different colored button, I didn't try that before but should work) and you may also want to look at the UIActionSheet. http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/04/14/iphone-uiactionsheet-example/
sending the cancel and destructive button titles to nil

Comment: Alrite thanx again Ehab Amer.

Answer (score 3):

You can set a variable, say `firstRun = YES` into user preferences.
When you launch the app, check the value from user preferences, if it is true, prompt the alert and do you job.

After that, change the value to NO so next time the user launch it will not prompt the alert. again.

Answer (score 1):

as Hanon says but at first time you didn't get the value of firstRun so simply check firstRun is equal to NO and at first time you found firstRun=NO then show your alert and on click on alert button save title in db and also set firstRun to YES so that next time alert could not displayed.